# How to get array name. Blade.Laravel.PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an array like this. Inside the `items` array, there is an array with a number (in our case, it is 3), this is the product id. Is it possible to get this id number from blade in laravel? Of course I can make an `id` field for this array, but I am wondering if the name of the array can be obtained in this case?

```
stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Hotpoint-Ariston HFZ 6175 S
                    [qty] => 1
                    [prod_url] => hotpoint_ariston_hfz_6175_s
                    [code_cat] => large-home-appliances
                    [url_cat] => freezers
                    [img] => img_5.jpg
                    [cost] => 250
                )

        )

    [totalQty] => 1
    [totalPrice] => 250
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Blade foreach loops](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops) work the same way as [PHP foreach loops](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), so you can access the key easily

```
@foreach($obj->items as $id => $item)
    {{ $id }} {{ $item['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the `index` of the `items` using a loop:

```
@foreach ($object as $index => $item)
  {{-- do something --}}
@endforeach
```

If you just want all the index values from `$items`, you can use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$indexs = array_keys($object->items);
```